# Python: How can I set the default behaviour of NoneType objects?

Tags: python, list, nonetype, built-in

I have created my own class that inherits from python's default list class. A simplified version is the following, that contains the `__abs__` method so I can use python's `abs` function.

```
class DataSet(list):

    def __abs__(self):
        result = []
        for i in self:
            result.append(abs(i))
        return result
```

Suppose have a DataSet that sometimes contains a `NoneType` value, for example

```
>>> dataset = DataSet([1, 2, 3, None, -1, -2, -3])
```

If I want to know the absolute value of this DataSet, I use the function

```
>>> abs_dataset = abs(dataset)
```

The result that I want to get is

```
[1, 2, 3, None, 1, 2, 3]
```

but because there is a value of type `NoneType` in the dataset, I get the error

```
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'NoneType'
```

For this one case it can be fixed by modifying the DataSet's `__abs__` function and to check for `None` in the individual elements of the DataSet, but in my case I have more cases where a `None` value can occur and I also want to implement more builtin functions than only `abs`.
Is there a method to set this default behaviour of default python functions like `abs` to `None` values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```py
class DataSet(list):

    def __abs__(self):
        # Here if i is 0 then it'll be 0. 
        # No need to check for `None`.
        return [abs(i) if i else i for i in self]

dataset = DataSet([1, 2, 3, None, -1, -2, -3])
print(abs(dataset))
# [1, 2, 3, None, 1, 2, 3]
```

**Edits:**
As mentioned by @juanpa.arrivillaga, if you want to filter the `None` type elements then you can do something like `[abs(i) for i in self if i is not None]` inside list comprehension.

Comment: you should explicitly check for None... this will filter out 0's

Comment: Right. Updated it.

Comment: use `i is not None` for more idiomatic code

Answer (score 2):

There isn't. And for a good reason. Other code can rely on None type bahaviour.

What you can do is provide method on DataSet which provide filtered list without None values and use it for your methods.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit those methods in order to make sure there will be no None in your dataset.

- `__setattr__`
- `__setitem__`
- `append`
- `extend`
- `insert`

just override them with a check for None, if there is change the value to 0/cancel the operation.